# Problems with DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#

I am trying to follow the conventions and I decided to create an OrderRepository class, I am trying to write some test before implementing the Retrieve method and code it for access to the database.

I am having a hard time understanding how to manipulate date and time, as I am hard coding it for the purpose of the test.

The last arg where I inserted (***???) is asking a TimeSpan Offset.

And I have done lots of research looking for a way to implement it and I confess that I didn't understand it.

```
public class OrderRepository
{
    public Order Retrieve(int orderId)
    {
        Order order = new Order(orderId);
        if (orderId == 10 )
        {
            order.OrderDate = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 04, 10, 23, 41, 00,***???);
        }

        return order;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. It's a `TimeSpan` that represents the offset from UTC.  From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354978(v=vs.110).aspx) it says: **"*offset* - Type: [`System.TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) The time's offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)."**

Comment: what is it that u want to achieve , can u clarify ?

Comment: If you want the `OrderDate` to be exactly that time, just pass `TimeSpan.Zero`.

Comment: Thank you guys, now i got it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument needs a TimeSpan that indicates your time zone distance from UTC. If you were located in Greenwich (which is at UTC+0), it would be

```
order.OrderDate = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 04, 10, 23, 41, 00, new TimeSpan(0,0,0));
```

If you were located on the east coast of the United States (five hours difference), it would be

```
order.OrderDate = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 04, 10, 23, 41, 00, new TimeSpan(-5,0,0));
```

Notice that we are only using the first constructor parameter (hours) since most time zones fall on an hour boundary. In a few cases, you might need the second parameter (minutes) too, for example, India is GMT+5.5 hours:

```
order.OrderDate = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 04, 10, 23, 41, 00, new TimeSpan(5,30,0));
```

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for the clarification.
It makes sense, but I think I was overthinking it a bit.

Thanks for the support.